# Read in powerpoint theme colours in python-pptx

Tags: python-pptx

Is there a way to read theme colours aka Accent colours from a given powerpoint via python-pptx?

I'm hoping someone has an undocumented way of doing this because this feature does not exist in the library right now.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you'll need to access the theme part, get its XML, then either parse it or use some sort of regular expression search to find the values you want.

The XML you're looking for looks like this:

```
<a:theme
    xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"
    name="Office Theme">
  <a:themeElements>
    <a:clrScheme name="Office">
      <a:dk1><a:srgbClr val="444444"/></a:dk1>
      <a:lt1><a:srgbClr val="FFFFFF"/></a:lt1>
      <a:dk2><a:srgbClr val="888888"/></a:dk2>
      <a:lt2><a:srgbClr val="DFDFDF"/></a:lt2>
      <a:accent1><a:srgbClr val="306396"/></a:accent1>
      <a:accent2><a:srgbClr val="D03E3E"/></a:accent2>
      <a:accent3><a:srgbClr val="FDB72A"/></a:accent3>
      <a:accent4><a:srgbClr val="37AD6C"/></a:accent4>
      <a:accent5><a:srgbClr val="8A479B"/></a:accent5>
      <a:accent6><a:srgbClr val="1CBECF"/></a:accent6>
      <a:hlink><a:srgbClr val="0563C1"/></a:hlink>
      <a:folHlink><a:srgbClr val="954F72"/></a:folHlink>
    </a:clrScheme>
```

and you can access the parts you want with this (may need some tweaking):

```
from pptx.opc.constants import RELATIONSHIP_TYPE as RT
from pptx.oxml import parse_xml
from pptx.oxml.ns import qn  # ---makes qualified name---

# ---access the theme part---
prs = Presentation("presentation-with-theme-I-want-colors-from.pptx")
presentation_part = prs.part
theme_part = presentation_part.part_related_by(RT.THEME)

# ---access theme XML from part---
theme_xml = theme_part.blob
print(theme_xml) # ---should look like example above, just longer---

# ---parse XML---
theme_element = parse_xml(theme_xml)

# ---find color elements---
color_elements = theme_element.xpath(".//%s/child::*" % qn("a:clrScheme"))
print(len(color_elements)  # ---should be 12, of which you care about 6---
for e in color_elements:
    print(e.tag)
    print(e[0].get("val"))
```

The latter parts here use the `lxml.etree._Element` interface, which you can study online to do different operations if you need them.
https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve! Really appreciate your time. I can now extract the 1-6 hex theme colors from a given template :)